# PowerShell Install-Module Command fails in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have the following PowerShell cmdlet to install PowerShell module when the pipeline is being executed

```
steps:
    - powershell: |
    
        Install-PackageProvider Nuget -Scope CurrentUser -Force
        Install-module PSScriptAnalyzer -force -Scope CurrentUser
        Install-module PSPesterTest -force -Scope CurrentUser
      displayName: 'Install required PowerShell modules'
```

This however throws an error of `"No repository with the name 'PSGallery' was found"`.
Please, can anyone, point me to a workaround with regards this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your script syntax, please try the following script:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
      Install-Module -Name PSScriptAnalyzer -Force -Scope CurrentUser
      Install-Module -Name PSPesterTest -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

[image]

Here is the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7) you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*:

`Install-module` should be `Install-Module`.
Moreover,by restoring the PSRespository back to default your problem is hopefully resolved :)

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
```